# How to implement Dark mode and Light Mode in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, themes, android-dark-theme

I want to create a flutter app that has 2 light and dark mode themes that change by a switch in-app and the default theme is default android theme.
I need to pass some custom color to the fellow widget and I don't want to just config material theme.

- how to detect the user device default theme?
- the secend question is how to provide a theme to the whole app?
- third is how change the theme with a simple switch in running time?

Comment: Did I understand you correctly, you have 3 themes, light mode, dark mode and a default android theme? The user can switching between the light- and dark mode theme?


What exactly do you mean with `need to pass some custom color to the fellow widget`?

Comment: no, I have dark mode and light mode only bypassing color I mean I have 2 colors white and grey for the background and border in the fellow widget  so instead if write `background:Colors.white` i want `background:store.xColor`

Comment: Check my answer below, You should use ThemeMode.system to detect system theme.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

The easiest way in my opinion is by using provider to manage the state of your app and shared_preferences to save your theme preference on file system. By following this procedure you can save your theme so the user doesn't have to switch theme every time.

**Output**
[image]

You can easily store your theme preference in form of a string and then at the start of your app check if there is value stored on file system, if so apply that theme as shown below.

**StorageManager.dart**

```
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class StorageManager {
  static void saveData(String key, dynamic value) async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    if (value is int) {
      prefs.setInt(key, value);
    } else if (value is String) {
      prefs.setString(key, value);
    } else if (value is bool) {
      prefs.setBool(key, value);
    } else {
      print("Invalid Type");
    }
  }

  static Future<dynamic> readData(String key) async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    dynamic obj = prefs.get(key);
    return obj;
  }

  static Future<bool> deleteData(String key) async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    return prefs.remove(key);
  }
}
```

Define your theme properties in a theme variable like below and initialize your _themedata variable on the basis of value inside storage.

**ThemeManager.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../services/storage_manager.dart';

class ThemeNotifier with ChangeNotifier {
  final darkTheme = ThemeData(
    primarySwatch: Colors.grey,
    primaryColor: Colors.black,
    brightness: Brightness.dark,
    backgroundColor: const Color(0xFF212121),
    accentColor: Colors.white,
    accentIconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.black),
    dividerColor: Colors.black12,
  );

  final lightTheme = ThemeData(
    primarySwatch: Colors.grey,
    primaryColor: Colors.white,
    brightness: Brightness.light,
    backgroundColor: const Color(0xFFE5E5E5),
    accentColor: Colors.black,
    accentIconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.white),
    dividerColor: Colors.white54,
  );

  ThemeData _themeData;
  ThemeData getTheme() => _themeData;

  ThemeNotifier() {
    StorageManager.readData('themeMode').then((value) {
      print('value read from storage: ' + value.toString());
      var themeMode = value ?? 'light';
      if (themeMode == 'light') {
        _themeData = lightTheme;
      } else {
        print('setting dark theme');
        _themeData = darkTheme;
      }
      notifyListeners();
    });
  }

  void setDarkMode() async {
    _themeData = darkTheme;
    StorageManager.saveData('themeMode', 'dark');
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void setLightMode() async {
    _themeData = lightTheme;
    StorageManager.saveData('themeMode', 'light');
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Wrap your app with themeProvider and then apply theme using consumer. By doing so whenever you change the value of theme and call notify listeners widgets rebuild to sync changes.

**Main.dart**

```
void main() {
  return runApp(ChangeNotifierProvider<ThemeNotifier>(
    create: (_) => new ThemeNotifier(),
    child: MyApp(),
  ));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<ThemeNotifier>(
      builder: (context, theme, _) => MaterialApp(
        theme: theme.getTheme(),
        home: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('Hybrid Theme'),
          ),
          body: Row(
            children: [
              Container(
                child: FlatButton(
                  onPressed: () => {
                    print('Set Light Theme'),
                    theme.setLightMode(),
                  },
                  child: Text('Set Light Theme'),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                child: FlatButton(
                  onPressed: () => {
                    print('Set Dark theme'),
                    theme.setDarkMode(),
                  },
                  child: Text('Set Dark theme'),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[Here](https://github.com/mateenkiani/theming_flutter) is the link to github repository.

Comment: This render slow if you are setting modes in somewhere down the widget hierarchy and not the root widget.

Comment: Normally apps have dark mode settings in-app settings. Do we need to use the MaterialApp widget there too? Let's say I don't want to change it from the home screen. How should I place the notifiers?

Comment: No you don't need a material widget where you need to change the theme. You can use consumer any where in the code and get the theme object and then by using that object you can easily switch theme. Here is a link to a sample app that does what you are looking for https://github.com/mateenkiani/Inventory_management/blob/master/lib/src/Pages/SettingsPage.dart

Comment: I'm new to Flutter and am trying to implement what you have here using Flutter 3 and Dart 2.17. I'm getting a build error in ThemeManager.dart: `Error: Field '_themeData' should be initialized because its type 'ThemeData' doesn't allow null.` It seems the `getTheme()` method on the next line is the initializer, but it doesn't like the uninitialized property above it. Any ideas?

Comment: Hi! I get an error `Non-nullable instance field '_themeData' must be initialized.
Try adding an initializer expression, or add a field initializer in this constructor, or mark it 'late'` in `ThemeNotifier()` function in `ThemeManager.dart` file. If I put `late` before `ThemeData _themeData;` I get an error `LateError (LateInitializationError: Field '_themeData@31353943' has not been initialized.)`. What is happening???!! 

Comment: Hi, I got this error:   ( Non-nullable instance field '_themeData' must be initialized., and 
 'accentColor' is deprecated and shouldn't be used. Use colorScheme.secondary instead. For more information, consult the migration guide at https://flutter.dev/docs/release/breaking-changes/theme-data-accent-properties#migration-guide. This feature was deprecated after v2.3.0-0.1.pre..)

Answer (score 189):

**Using Material App**

```
MaterialApp(
      title: 'App Title',
      theme: ThemeData(
        brightness: Brightness.light,
        /* light theme settings */
      ),
      darkTheme: ThemeData(
        brightness: Brightness.dark,
        /* dark theme settings */
      ),
      themeMode: ThemeMode.dark, 
      /* ThemeMode.system to follow system theme, 
         ThemeMode.light for light theme, 
         ThemeMode.dark for dark theme
      */
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: YourAppHomepage(),
    );
```

**Using CupertinoApp**

1. Detect the dark mode using, `WidgetsBinding.instance?.window.platformBrightness`
2. You may also have to listen for the brightness changes from the system in order to update in real-time using `WidgetsBindingObserver`, and overriding, `didChangePlatformBrightness();`

**CupertinoApp Example:**

```
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> with WidgetsBindingObserver {
  Brightness? _brightness;

  @override
  void initState() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance?.addObserver(this);
    _brightness = WidgetsBinding.instance?.window.platformBrightness;
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance?.removeObserver(this);
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void didChangePlatformBrightness() {
    if (mounted) {
      setState(() {
        _brightness = WidgetsBinding.instance?.window.platformBrightness;
      });
    }

    super.didChangePlatformBrightness();
  }

  CupertinoThemeData get _lightTheme =>
      CupertinoThemeData(brightness: Brightness.light, /* light theme settings */);

  CupertinoThemeData get _darkTheme => CupertinoThemeData(
        brightness: Brightness.dark, /* dark theme settings */,
      );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CupertinoApp(
      title: 'Demo App',
      theme: _brightness == Brightness.dark ? _darkTheme : _lightTheme,
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}
```

You can use [scoped_model](https://pub.dev/packages/scoped_model), [provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider), [bloc](https://pub.dev/packages/bloc) or [get](https://pub.dev/packages/get) for seamless experience.

Comment: For other readers: you need to restart the application. Hot reloading after changing it to thememode.system does not work.

Comment: How to do this with CupertinoApp?

Comment: @MuhammadQasim Check the updated answer!

Comment: @RajYadav, your solution looks very clean. Could you please post a version using the provider to achieve the same behavior? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Excellent solution! **However as of Flutter 3.10.1 (at the moment of writing), the `window` property has been deprecated**. This is the message: `Deprecated. Will be removed in a future version of Flutter. This property has been deprecated to prepare for Flutter's upcoming support for multiple views and multiple windows.` **As an alternative it is said to** `Look up the current FlutterView from the context via View.of(context) or consult the PlatformDispatcher directly instead.`

Answer (score 107):

Below are three ways to implement Dark Mode:

- always Dark mode
- device/platform controlled dark mode
- app controlled, runtime switchable dark mode

## Always Dark Mode

To run your app only in Dark Mode:

- in `MaterialApp`, replace `ThemeData(...)` with `ThemeData.dark()`
- restart your app. It will now be running in Dark Mode using the colors defined in `ThemeData.dark()`

**OLD**

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}
```

**NEW**

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData.dark(), // default dark theme replaces default light theme
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}
```

## Device Controlled Dark Mode

- works only on Android 10+, iOS 13+ (when dark mode was introduced)
- to let the device/platform set the theme, `MaterialApp` needs 3 args:

  - `theme: ThemeData()`
  - `darkTheme: ThemeData().dark`
  - `themeMode: ThemeMode.system`

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(),
      darkTheme: ThemeData.dark(), // standard dark theme
      themeMode: ThemeMode.system, // device controls theme
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}
```

- (you can use custom themes. Above are defaults for simplicity)
- `themeMode: ThemeMode.system` tells Flutter to use the device/platform theme setting
- with the above settings on Android 10+ or iOS 13+, toggling Dark mode via Device Settings will now switch your app between light and dark modes.

  - on Android: drag down from top of screen and click the [Dark theme toggle button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bb3tV.jpg).
  - iOS **physical device**: Settings > Display & Brightness > Light or Dark.
  - iOS: [add Dark mode switch to Control Center](https://9to5mac.com/2019/09/04/add-ios-13-dark-mode-shortcut-iphone/) for ease of testing
  - iOS **simulator**: Settings > Developer > Dark Appearance.
- any time the device theme changes, your app will immediately reflect the chosen device theme
- to get the current device theme mode programmatically, we can check device brightness (`Brightness.light` or `Brightness.dark`) which corresponds to light mode and dark mode. Do this by querying `platformBrightness` with: `MediaQuery.of(context).platformBrightness`

## App Controlled Dark Mode

- our app can run in either light or dark mode, controlled by user and switched freely at runtime inside the app and completely ignore the device's theme setting
- as before, supply all three theme arguments to `MaterialApp`: `theme:`, `darkTheme:` and `themeMode:`, but we'll adjust `themeMode:` to use a state field below
- To switch between light / dark modes within the app, we'll swap the `themeMode:` argument between `ThemeMode.light` and `ThemeMode.dark` and rebuild the `MaterialApp` widget.

**How to Rebuild MaterialApp widget**

- to switch our app theme from anywhere, we need to access `MaterialApp` from anywhere in our app
- we can do this without any package using just `StatefulWidget`, or we can use a state management package
- example of runtime theme switching anywhere in app using StatefulWidget below

**Before - Stateless**

- we started with this, but we'll replace it with a `StatefulWidget` next

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(),
      darkTheme: ThemeData.dark(), // standard dark theme
      themeMode: ThemeMode.system, // device controls theme
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}
```

**After - Stateful**

- here we've replaced `MyApp` `StatelessWidget` with a `StatefulWidget` and its complementary `State` class, `_MyAppState`

```
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(),
      darkTheme: ThemeData.dark(), // standard dark theme
      themeMode: ThemeMode.system, // device controls theme
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}
```

**Add Static Accessor to `StatefulWidget`**

- adding this static `of()` method to our `StatefulWidget` makes its `State` object accessible for any descendant widget

```
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();

  /// ↓↓ ADDED
  /// InheritedWidget style accessor to our State object. 
  static _MyAppState of(BuildContext context) => 
      context.findAncestorStateOfType<_MyAppState>()!;
}

/// State object hidden ↓. Focusing on ↑ StatefulWidget here.
```

- note the return `Type` of our `of()` method: `_MyAppState`
- we're not getting the `StatefulWidget`, we're getting its `State` object: `_MyAppState`
- `_MyAppState` will hold the "state" of our `ThemeMode` setting (in next step). This is what controls our app's current theme.
- next in our `_MyAppState` class we'll add a `ThemeMode` "state" field and a method to change theme & rebuild our app

**_MyAppState**

- below is our `State` class modified with:

  1. a "state" field `_themeMode`
  2. `MaterialApp` `themeMode:` arg using `_themeMode` state field value
  3. `changeTheme` method

```
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  /// 1) our themeMode "state" field
  ThemeMode _themeMode = ThemeMode.system;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(),
      darkTheme: ThemeData.dark(),
      themeMode: _themeMode, // 2) ← ← ← use "state" field here //////////////
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }

  /// 3) Call this to change theme from any context using "of" accessor
  /// e.g.:
  /// MyApp.of(context).changeTheme(ThemeMode.dark);
  void changeTheme(ThemeMode themeMode) {
    setState(() {
      _themeMode = themeMode;
    });
  }
}
```

- next, we'll show how to access `changeTheme()` to change our theme & rebuild the app

**Change Theme & Rebuild**

- below is an example of using the `of()` accessor method to find our `State` object and call its changeTheme method from the two buttons below which call:

  - `MyApp.of(context).changeTheme(ThemeMode.light)`
  - `MyApp.of(context).changeTheme(ThemeMode.dark)`

```
class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;

  MyHomePage({required this.title});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'Choose your theme:',
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: [
                /// //////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                /// Change theme & rebuild to show it using these buttons 
                ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () => MyApp.of(context).changeTheme(ThemeMode.light),
                    child: Text('Light')),
                ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () => MyApp.of(context).changeTheme(ThemeMode.dark),
                    child: Text('Dark')),
                /// //////////////////////////////////////////////////////
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: change theme buttons]

To return theme control back to the device's Dark mode setting, create a third button that makes a call to set `themeMode:` to `ThemeMode.system`:

- `MyApp.of(context).changeTheme(ThemeMode.system)`

Running this method will delegate control of the app's theme back to whatever Dark mode setting the device is currently using.

**Code**: Complete copy-paste code [available in this gist](https://gist.github.com/ben-xx/10000ed3bf44e0143cf0fe7ac5648254).

Comment: Broooooo. thank you soooo much bruh!!!

Comment: i used 
```bool darkModeOn(context) =>
    Theme.of(context).brightness == Brightness.dark;``` to find the app theme if anyone like me also searching for this

Comment: thx very nice, helped a lot

Answer (score 24):

**Letting the system handle themes:**

```dart
runApp(
  MaterialApp(
    theme: ThemeData.light(), // Provide light theme
    darkTheme: ThemeData.dark(), // Provide dark theme
    home: HomePage(),
  ),
);
```

---

**Handling the themes yourself:**

[image]

Use [provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) to set the theme programmatically. Full code:

```dart
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider<ThemeModel>(
      create: (_) => ThemeModel(),
      child: Consumer<ThemeModel>(
        builder: (_, model, __) {
          return MaterialApp(
            theme: ThemeData.light(), // Provide light theme.
            darkTheme: ThemeData.dark(), // Provide dark theme.
            themeMode: model.mode, // Decides which theme to show. 
            home: Scaffold(
              appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Light/Dark Theme')),
              body: ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () => model.toggleMode(),
                child: Text('Toggle Theme'),
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ThemeModel with ChangeNotifier {
  ThemeMode _mode;
  ThemeMode get mode => _mode;
  ThemeModel({ThemeMode mode = ThemeMode.light}) : _mode = mode;

  void toggleMode() {
    _mode = _mode == ThemeMode.light ? ThemeMode.dark : ThemeMode.light;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

---

Answering OP questions:

- Current theme can be found using:

  ```
  bool isDarkMode = MediaQuery.of(context).platformBrightness == Brightness.dark;
  ```

  or

  ```
  bool isDarkMode = SchedulerBinding.instance.window.platformBrightness == Brightness.dark;
  ```
- You can provide theme to your whole app using `theme` for default themes, `darkTheme` for Dark themes (if dark mode is enabled by the system or by you using `themeMode`)
- You can make use of provider package as shown in the code above.

Comment: How to do this with CupertinoApp?

Comment: But this does not persist.

Answer (score 14):

```
MaterialApp(
  theme: ThemeData.light(),
  /// theme: ThemeData.dark(),
)
```

Down the widget tree, you can access ThemeData simply by writing `Theme.of(context)`. If you want to access the current ThemeData and provide your own styling for certain field, you can do for an instance:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  var themeData = Theme.of(context).copyWith(scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue)

  return Scaffold(
    backgroundColor = themeData.scaffoldBackgroundColor,
  );
}
```

But to handle the ThemeData state (changing its value), you need to implement proper state management.

Comment: That's one example of state management in flutter, there are provider package and flutter_bloc as well. To answer how to do it is very wide question, maybe you can find tutorials about it

Answer (score 12):

**Screenshot:**

[image]

---

If you don't want to use any third party packages or plugins, you can use `ValueListenableBuilder` which comes out of the box with Flutter.

**Full code:**

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final ValueNotifier<ThemeMode> _notifier = ValueNotifier(ThemeMode.light);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ValueListenableBuilder<ThemeMode>(
      valueListenable: _notifier,
      builder: (_, mode, __) {
        return MaterialApp(
          theme: ThemeData.light(),
          darkTheme: ThemeData.dark(),
          themeMode: mode, // Decides which theme to show, light or dark.
          home: Scaffold(
            body: Center(
              child: ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () => _notifier.value = mode == ThemeMode.light ? ThemeMode.dark : ThemeMode.light,
                child: Text('Toggle Theme'),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.light(), // Provide light theme.
      darkTheme: ThemeData.dark(), // Provide dark theme.
      themeMode: ThemeMode.system,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(),
        body: Container(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Here is a code 
In this code you i've made custom theme according to my requirements you can change it!!

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Theme',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,

      /* light theme settings */
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        primaryColor: Colors.white,
        brightness: Brightness.light,
        accentColor: Colors.black,
        accentIconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.white),
        dividerColor: Colors.white54,
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.white,

      ),

      /* Dark theme settings */
      darkTheme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        primaryColor: Colors.black,
        brightness: Brightness.dark,
        accentColor: Colors.white,
        accentIconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.black),
        dividerColor: Colors.black12,
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: Color(0xFF131313),

      ),

      /* ThemeMode.system to follow system theme,
         ThemeMode.light for light theme,
         ThemeMode.dark for dark theme */
      themeMode: ThemeMode.system,

      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: that's most simple one

Answer (score 5):

```
  theme: ThemeData.light(), // Provide light theme.
  darkTheme: ThemeData.dark(), // Provide dark theme.
  themeMode: ThemeMode.system,


  //use only these three line for dynamic change theme respect to system theme.
```

Answer (score 5):

Little late to the party you can implement it without any third party state management using the built-in ValueNotifier.This approach allows you to change the theme of your entire app from any part of the app.

Heres the [dartpad demo](https://dartpad.dev/?id=9e93976f0d07abb412790ca1585c6448&null_safety=true)

See this for changing theme with [Telegram like transition](https://gist.github.com/maheshmnj/815642f5576ebef0a0747db6854c2a74)

[image]

Complete code sample

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

final darkNotifier = ValueNotifier<bool>(false);

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ValueListenableBuilder<bool>(
        valueListenable: darkNotifier,
        builder: (BuildContext context, bool isDark, Widget? child) {
          return MaterialApp(
            title: 'Flutter Demo',
            themeMode: isDark ? ThemeMode.dark : ThemeMode.light,
            theme: ThemeData(primaryColor: Colors.blue),
            darkTheme: ThemeData.dark(),
            home: MyHomePage(
              title: 'Homepage',
            ),
          );
        });
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  void dispose() {
    // TODO: implement dispose
    darkNotifier.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    bool isDark = darkNotifier.value;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              _darkNotifier.value ? 'DarkMode' : 'LightMode',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          isDark = !isDark;
          darkNotifier.value = isDark;
        },
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(isDark ? Icons.wb_sunny_outlined : Icons.bubble_chart),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: hey, MyHomePage class is in a new dart file. How can I Implement this in that case? @Mahesh Jamdade

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem you can call`darkNotifier.value` from anywhere. I implemented this approach in this app https://vocabhub.web.app/#/ and it works pretty well. And the code is open sourced to have a look

Comment: Will whole MaterialApp be rebuilt when you change the theme?

Comment: yes, the entire tree needs to rebuild, since`ValueListenableBuilder` is at the root of the tree.

Answer (score 5):

**For Customize `dark` theme**

as per your need use `darkTheme: ThemeData( use theme properties you need in dark mode)`

**description:**

if `dark` mode is selected in your system then flutter uses `darkTheme` property of `MaterialApp`  and if light is selected then flutter uses `theme` property of `MaterialApp`, below code shows when you select (try it in your cellphone) `dark` option in your system then your app will show `scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.red` and if you select `light` then it will show `scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.amber`

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      darkTheme: ThemeData(brightness: Brightness.dark, scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.red),
      theme: ThemeData(
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.amber,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
```

**Full code**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      darkTheme: ThemeData(brightness: Brightness.dark, scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.red),
      // themeMode: ThemeMode.dark,
      theme: ThemeData(
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.amber,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    // print("brightness ${ColorScheme.}")
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'increment',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Below is the simple example for changing the theme light to dark[image]

```
    import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
    import 'package:theme_mode_switch/notify.dart';
    
    void main() {
      runApp(
          ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => DarkMode(), child: MyApp()));
    }
    
    
    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        final thmode = Provider.of<DarkMode>(context); ///accessing the variable of provider class
        return MaterialApp(
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          title: 'Dark Mode',
          theme: ThemeData(
            ///here the value of darmode var is updationg by switching
            brightness: thmode.darkMode ? Brightness.dark : Brightness.light,
            primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
            visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
          ),
          home: MyHomePage(),
        );
      }
    }
    
    class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {      
        final thmode = Provider.of<DarkMode>(context);
        return Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text('Dark Mode'),
            ),
            body: Center(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(thmode.darkMode ? 'Dark' :'Light'),
                  CupertinoSwitch(
                    value: thmode.darkMode,
                    onChanged: (bool val) {
                      thmode.changemode();
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ));
      }
    }


class DarkMode with ChangeNotifier {
  bool darkMode = true; ///by default it is true
  ///made a method which will execute while switching
  changemode() {
    darkMode = !darkMode;
    notifyListeners(); ///notify the value or update the widget value
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the available plugin [day_night_theme_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/day_night_theme_flutter)

A Flutter plugin that helps you to automatically change the theme of the app with sunrise and sunset. Just specify the light and dark theme to use, and you are all set. You can use your custom sunrise and sunset time too.

How to use it?

1. Add the latest version of the package in your pubspec.yaml
2. Wrap the MaterialApp with DayNightTheme Widget.

Answer (score 3):

I've found a very nice [approach](https://itnext.io/an-easy-way-to-switch-between-dark-and-light-theme-in-flutter-fb971155eefe) from ITnext where no third-party packages (except for either shared_preferences or hive) are necessary. Here a short summary (without the imports and with a switcher):

```
// this makes all variables available globally
library config.globals;

// initialize the theme model once
ThemeModel currentTheme = ThemeModel();
// also declare the box
Box? box;
```

**config.dart**

```
class ThemeModel with ChangeNotifier {
  // initialize the standard theme here, possible with an elvis to check for the brightness
  static bool _isDark = false;
  // set a getter just for a more clean approach
  bool get isDark => _isDark;

  ThemeModel() {
    // check for a stored value on initialization
    if(box!.containsKey("currentTheme")) {
      _isDark = box!.get("currentTheme");
    } else {
      // if there is no value, apply the standard theme
      box!.put("currentTheme", _isDark);
    }
  }

  ThemeMode currentTheme() {
    return _isDark ? ThemeMode.dark : ThemeMode.light;
  }

  void switchTheme() {
    // switches the theme by reversing the boolean
    _isDark = !_isDark;
    // storing the new value
    box!.put("currentTheme", _isDark);
    // notifies all listeners attached to the theme model
    notifyListeners();
  }

}
```

**theme_model.dart**

```
void main() async {
  // waits for the hive init before running the app
  box = await Hive.openBox("theme");
  runApp(YourApp());
}

class YourApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _YourAppState createState() => _YourAppState();
}

class _YourAppState extends State<YourApp> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // we are setting a listener to the currentTheme, 
    // so it gets notified once we toggle it
    currentTheme.addListener(() {
      setState((){});
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Your title',
      theme: ThemeData().light,
      darkTheme: ThemeData().dark,
      // it will always listen to changes made to currentTheme
      themeMode: currentTheme.currentTheme(),
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}
```

**main.dart**

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {    
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Switch(
            // looking for the current value and sets the switch state
            value: currentTheme.isDark,
            onChanged: (value) {
              setState(() {
                // we then set the state to the new current theme
                currentTheme.switchTheme();
              });
            },
          ),
          // this is just a text next to the switch stating the current theme
          Text("${currentTheme.currentTheme().toString().split(".")[1]} mode"),
        ],
      );
    );
  }
}
```

**homepage.dart**

You can set the default value to ThemeData.system, if you want to get the users ui preferences. You have to adjust the code to look after the current brightness and then set the theme regarding to the state of it. After that it uses a switch to toggle between dark and light mode.

[Example gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/95dWG.gif)

Answer (score 3):

Multiple Flutter themes example (Light and Dark theme)

1. Add provider in .yaml file
2. Declare runApp method like this

> runApp(ChangeNotifierProvider(
> create: (context) => ThemeState(),
> child: MyApp(),
> ));

3. Create `ThemeState` class and `extend` it with `ChangeNotitifer`

```dart
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

    enum ThemeType { DARK, LIGHT }
    
    class ThemeState extends ChangeNotifier {
      bool _isDarkTheme = false;
    
      ThemeState() {
        getTheme().then((type) {
          _isDarkTheme = type == ThemeType.DARK;
          notifyListeners();
        });
      }
      ThemeType get theme => _isDarkTheme ? ThemeType.DARK : ThemeType.LIGHT;
      set theme(ThemeType type) => setTheme(type);
    
      void setTheme(ThemeType type) async {
        _isDarkTheme = type == ThemeType.DARK;
        notifyListeners();
      }
    
      Future<ThemeType> getTheme() async {
        return _isDarkTheme ? ThemeType.DARK : ThemeType.LIGHT;
      }
    }
```

4. In the MyApp class declare this in MaterialApp like this

```dart
    theme: Provider.of<ThemeState>(context).theme == ThemeType.DARK
                ? ThemeData(
                    // Define the default brightness and colors.
                    brightness: Brightness.dark,
                    primaryColor: Colors.lightBlue[800],
                    // Define the default font family.
                    fontFamily: 'Georgia',
                    // Define the default `TextTheme`. Use this to specify the default
                    // text styling for headlines, titles, bodies of text, and more.
                    textTheme: const TextTheme(
                      headline1:
                          TextStyle(fontSize: 32.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      headline6:
                          TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0, fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
                      bodyText2: TextStyle(fontSize: 10.0, fontFamily: 'Hind'),
                    ),
                  )
                : ThemeData(
                    // Define the default brightness and colors.
                    brightness: Brightness.light,
                    primaryColor: Colors.lightGreen[300],
                    // Define the default font family.
                    fontFamily: 'Georgia',
                    // Define the default `TextTheme`. Use this to specify the default
                    // text styling for headlines, titles, bodies of text, and more.
                    textTheme: const TextTheme(
                      headline1:
                          TextStyle(fontSize: 32.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.normal),
                      headline6:
                          TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0, fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
                      bodyText2: TextStyle(fontSize: 10.0, fontFamily: 'Hind'),
                    ),
                  ),
```

Answer (score 3):

This is the current up-to-date method apparently:

```
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorSchemeSeed: Colors.green,
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      darkTheme: ThemeData(
        colorSchemeSeed: Colors.green,
        brightness: Brightness.dark,
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
```

You don't need to set `themeMode` - the default is to use the system theme which is what you should want.

If you use `colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.green)` in the `darkTheme` you will get an assertion failure because the `colorScheme.brightness` has to match `darkTheme.brightness`. You can "fix" it like this: `colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.green).copyWith(brightness: Brightness.dark)` but that won't actually change the colours - your dark theme will look light.

You can use `ThemeData.dark()` except then it won't be a Material 3 theme.

I recommend looking at [this example app](https://github.com/chayanforyou/flutter_material_3_demo/blob/master/lib/main.dart). Web demo [here](https://flutter.github.io/samples/web/material_3_demo/#/). It can change theme animated at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

much easier than you think with [get](https://pub.dev/packages/get#change-theme) package

```
return GetMaterialApp(
  themeMode: lightOrDark?ThemeMode.light:ThemeMode.dark,
  ...
);
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want Theme to your whole app with button toggled, simply you can use provider package, and make your main root listen to changes to mode

Make a class with changenotifier mixin that defines the your theme data with two instances of your dark and light mode

```
class LightDarkMode with ChangeNotifier {
var currentMode = false;

void switchMode(bool mode) {
  currentMode = mode;
  notifyListeners();
}

final light = const ColorScheme(
/*Light Color OF Icons*/ primary: Color.fromARGB(255, 126, 12, 12),
/*Dark Color OF Icon/Buttons*/ secondary: Color.fromARGB(255, 219, 203, 217),
onPrimary: Color.fromARGB(255, 163, 163, 163),
onSecondary: Colors.amber,
/*BACKGROUND OF APP*/ background: Color.fromARGB(255, 211, 204, 198),
/*Appbar,Big Widgets etc*/ onBackground: Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 0, 0),
surface: Color.fromARGB(255, 165, 158, 158),
onSurface: Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 0, 0),
error: Color.fromARGB(255, 233, 56, 44),
onError: Color.fromARGB(255, 124, 8, 0),
brightness: Brightness.light,
);

final dark = const ColorScheme(
/*Light Color OF Icons*/ primary: Color.fromARGB(255, 9, 75, 9),
/*Dark Color OF Icon/Buttons*/ secondary: Color.fromARGB(255, 23, 159, 168),
onPrimary: Colors.white,
onSecondary: Colors.amber,
/*BACKGROUND OF APP*/ background: Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 0, 0),
/*Appbar,Big Widgets etc*/ onBackground: Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 255, 255),
surface: Color.fromARGB(255, 231, 214, 199),
onSurface: Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 0, 0),
error: Color.fromARGB(255, 233, 56, 44),
onError: Color.fromARGB(255, 124, 8, 0),
brightness: Brightness.dark,
);
}
```

Now create an istance of your data class through main, and implement a listener to that instance, anywhere in your app like this:

```
        ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (context) => LightDarkMode(),
    )
  ],
  builder: (context, child) => Consumer<LightDarkMode>(
    builder: (context, value, child) => MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Demo',darkTheme: ThemeData() ,
      theme: ThemeData(colorScheme: value.currentMode ? value.dark : value.light),
      home: const Calculator(),
    ),


Widget build(BuildContext context) {
final device = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
      centerTitle: true,
      title: const Text(
        'Calculator',
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 24),
      ),
      backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
      actions: [
        Consumer<LightDarkMode>(
          builder: (context, value, child) => ToggleButtons(
            borderWidth: 0,
            isSelected: selected,
            onPressed: (index) {
              selected[0] = !selected[0];
              value.switchMode(selected[0]);
            },
            children: [Icon(value.currentMode == true ? Icons.mode_night : Icons.sunny, color: value.currentMode == true ? Colors.amber : Colors.white)],
          ),
        )
      ]),
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).