# flutter application to control mobile theme

Tags: flutter, controls, themes, device

Actually, I want a control button in my flutter application that can change the whole **device** theme - Dark/Light. I haven't found any related dependency

Comment: see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60232070/how-to-implement-dark-mode-in-flutter

Comment: He doesn't want to change the application's theme but the entire device's theme.

Answer (score 1):

You can't, while it is possible to detect if you are in light or dark mode to adapt your application the only way to change the whole device theme is by going in the device settings. Even in native android or iOS you cannot do it.