# How to set the color based on dark / light theme?

Tags: flutter, flutter-theme

I want to set a dark and a light color scheme and use it as a background color of containers.

Here is my code:

```
Container(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(kDefaultPadding),
  //change required here:
  decoration: const BoxDecoration(color: kDarkColor),
  child: ... ,
)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your root file (`main.dart`) your entry point of the app is located. In general, you have a `class MyApp` which returns a `MaterialApp` widget.  This out-of-the-box widget from the Flutter SDK lets you define your app´s theme. Here you can define the theme.

In your Container, you can assign the color directly via the color parameter. To refer to your theme data do this: `Theme.of(context).backgroundColor` for example.

Comment: FYI: You need to assign the color within the BoxDecoration if you e.g. use BoxDecoration parameters like shape.

Comment: You can now do `Theme.of(context).colorScheme.background` to avoid deprecation

Answer (score 1):

You can use `platformBrightness` from MediaQuery.

```dart
final isDarkTheme = MediaQuery.of(context).platformBrightness == Brightness.dark;

  Container(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(kDefaultPadding),
    //change required here
    decoration: const BoxDecoration(color: isDarkTheme? kDarkColor: kLightColor),
    child: Column(
    // ...
  ),
```

Also see [how to implement dark mode in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60232070/how-to-implement-dark-mode-in-flutter?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

We can achieve this by reading the color from ThemeData.

Setting Themes

```
// light Theme
ThemeData lightThemeData(BuildContext context) {
  return ThemeData.light().copyWith(
    backgroundColor: Colors.grey.shade100,
  );
}

// dark Theme
ThemeData darkThemeData(BuildContext context) {
  return ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
    backgroundColor: Colors.grey.shade900,
  );
}
```

Configuring Theme in MaterialApp

```
      theme: lightThemeData(context),
      darkTheme: darkThemeData(context),
```

Finally using it

```
BoxDecoration(color: Theme.of(context).backgroundColor),
```