# How to change entire app to dark and light theme on ontap flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

Does anyone know how to change entire app to darktheme and light theme on onTap?

Comment: You can refer to this question for your answer [How to implement Dark mode and Light Mode in flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60232070/how-to-implement-dark-mode-and-light-mode-in-flutter)

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use [SharedPreferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) and [provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) packages

- create new dart file and call it themeNotifier

  ```
  class ThemeNotifier extends ChangeNotifier {
      final String key = 'theme';
      SharedPreferences? _prefs;
      bool? _darkTheme;
      bool? get dark => _darkTheme;

      ThemeNotifier() {
        _darkTheme = true;
        _loadfromPrefs();
      }
      toggleTheme(){
        _darkTheme = !_darkTheme!;
        _saveToPrefs();
        notifyListeners();
      }


      _loadfromPrefs()async{
        _darkTheme = _prefs!.getBool(key);
        notifyListeners();
      }
      _saveToPrefs()async{
        _prefs!.setBool(key, _darkTheme!);
      }
    }
  ```
- now create a switcher to toggle between dark mode and light mode

  ```
    Widget _buildThemeSwitch() {
    return ListTile(
      title: Text(
        "Dark Mode",
        style: TextStyle(
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
        ),
      ),
      trailing: Consumer<ThemeNotifier>(
        builder: (context, notifier, child) => CupertinoSwitch(
          onChanged: (val) {
            notifier.toggleTheme();
          },
          value: notifier.dark!,
          activeColor: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
  ```
- in your main.dart

  ```
    void main() {
      runApp(MyApp());
    }

    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
      @override

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers:ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) =>            ThemeNotifier()),
  child: Consumer<ThemeNotifier>(
     builder: (context, ThemeNotifier notifier, child) {
          return MaterialApp(
            debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
            title: "app name",
            theme:notifier.dark! ? "Your dark theme" : "Your light theme",
            home: "your home page",
          );
        },
      ),
     );}}
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Try it,

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final ValueNotifier<ThemeMode> _notifier = ValueNotifier(ThemeMode.light);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ValueListenableBuilder<ThemeMode>(
      valueListenable: _notifier,
      builder: (_, mode, __) {
        return MaterialApp(
          theme: ThemeData.light(),
          darkTheme: ThemeData.dark(),
          themeMode: mode, // Decides which theme to show, light or dark.
          home: Scaffold(
            body: Center(
              child: ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () => _notifier.value = mode == ThemeMode.light ? ThemeMode.dark : ThemeMode.light,
                child: Text('Toggle Theme'),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```