# Switch between 3 color themes in settings page

Tags: flutter, dart

I want the user to be able to switch between 3 color themes in settings page. Right now I can only change the theme when I use this code in my main.dart file. What can I do to have this functionality in another page?

```
void main() {
  runApp(name());
}

enum AppTheme {
  LightTheme(),
  DarkTheme,
  CustomTheme;
}

extension AppThemeData on AppTheme {
  get data {
    switch (this) {
      case AppTheme.DarkTheme:
        return ThemeData.dark();
      case AppTheme.CustomTheme:
        return ThemeData(
          useMaterial3: true,
          colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSwatch().copyWith(
            secondary: Colors.deepPurple,
          ),
        );

      case AppTheme.LightTheme:
      default:
        return ThemeData.light();
    }
  }
}

class name extends StatefulWidget {
  const name({super.key});

  @override
  State<name> createState() => _nameState();
}

class _nameState extends State<name> {
  AppTheme theme = AppTheme.LightTheme;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Material App',
      theme: theme.data,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("test"),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Text("test"),
            for (final value in AppTheme.values)
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    theme = value;
                  });
                },
                child: Text(value.name),
              )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Any help is appreciated! Let me know if you have any questions

Comment: With [provider package](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) you can create a `ChangeNotifierProvider` above your `MaterialApp` to manage to selected theme, listen to the changes and adjust `themeMode` accordingly. This way you can get the provider from anywhere and update your theme.

Comment: Could you please show an example? I've tried combining different tutorials using provider to achieve this but no luck. Would also like to be able to add sharedpreferences

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://medium.com/iot-lab-kiit/theme-changer-using-provider-in-flutter-b5c9efff7d0c)?